# Is ARKit usable for outdoor navigation if we don't use ARGeoTrackingConfiguration?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

My question is: I would like to create an app where the user would create a starting point in the place where he/she actually is and place e.g. a 3D navigation arrow that leads to another arrow or to an object of interest, so that if another user arrives at that place, the navigation arrow is loaded with the correct orientation? Can this be done with any usable accuracy?

ARGeoTrackingConfiguration is only usable in mapped cities but I don't know if something like this can be achieved for example with WorldMaps by combining GPS navigation and compass including google maps. What tools could be used?

Comment: Here is a small [example](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-ios/tree/main/arcgis-ios-sdk-samples/Augmented%20reality/Navigate%20in%20AR) I created with world tracking configuration. It is possible when the GPS accuracy is high, but can drift quite a bit when you move away from the starting location. We used some custom strategy to re-align the AR camera location and GPS location, based on accuracy, location discrepancy, and timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

ARKit and RealityKit were created for `indoor`/`outdoor` world tracking. It's not necessary to use Geo Tracking if you are on a street. The purpose of using Geo Tracking is to place models with the help of "visual variant" of GPS data.

The only unpleasant drawback of using a world tracking outside is tracking errors accumulation if a distance from starting point is considerable (it's a problem of any AR framework, not only ARKit or RealityKit). It's up to you what tools to use to keep precise tracking and object placement. You are an "artist" of your AR app.

As a starting point use [this](https://github.com/ProjectDent/ARKit-CoreLocation) github project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm new to arKit, so I don't know what is possible with this framework. I have some idea but I don't know what exactly to focus on so I can start working on my application as soon as possible. Do you think it is achievable to store navigation arrows, let's say at a total distance of 100m apart so that you can actually navigate by them? I can't find a tutorial anywhere that focuses on a similar thing i.e. saving objects on the map with right orientation and reloading them on another device. I would be very grateful for any tips on where to start.

Comment: Start using this github project (look at GIFs below) – https://github.com/ProjectDent/ARKit-CoreLocation